# Refactoring 'match' in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've read official guide but still have misunderstanding.
Is this code able for refactoring?

```
match '/help',    :to => 'home#help'
match '/contact', :to => 'home#contact'
match '/about',   :to => 'home#about'
```

`help`, `contact` and `about` are the only actions in the controller `home`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this on a hunch and it's not mentioned in the documentation, but it looks like it works (I'm on rails 3.1):

```
controller :home do
  get 'help'
  get 'contact'
  get 'about'
end
```

This also creates the `help_url`, `help_path`, etc helpers.

One warning though, this restricts the http verbs to `GET`. If you have a `POST` action (as an example, for a contact form), you could do either:

```
controller :home do
  get 'help'
  match 'contact', :via => [:get, :post]
  get 'about'
end
```

or just:

```
controller :home do
  get 'help'
  match 'contact'
  get 'about'
end
```

which will allow all http verbs on the contact route. But I find it better to be explicit about the accepted verbs.

Comment: Yep, it sometimes looks like the rails routing DSL reads my mind. This isn't documented though, so I don't know how much you can rely on this.

Comment: @QvvQw thanks for asking the question, I didn't even know this before trying it!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use rails shorthand here and do:

```
match 'home/help'
match 'home/contact'
match 'home/about'
```

Since the method names match this should work.

Comment: Wouldn't this change the urls?

Answer (score 1):

you could of course do

```
match '/:action', :controller => :home, :constraints => { :action => /^(help|contact|about)$/ }
```

but this is neither prettier, nor really shorter